# jquery.fileupload.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function on jQuery-file-upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I tried to use [basic](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) example ([source](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic.html)) for [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki), files that I've included in my html are:

```
jquery.js
bootstrap.css
bootstrap.js

jquery.fileupload.css
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
```

Is there anything else that I should include to properly use `jquery-file-upload`?

My app doesn't need to use `jquery-ui`.
If `jquery-ui` is really a dependency to `jquery-file-upload`, is there any workaround to use it without `jquery-ui`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind, I should have read [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) first. Only `jquery-ui.widget.js` required, not whole `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

are loaded also matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
jquery.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.iframe-transport.js
jquery.fileupload.js
```

and finally

```
$('#input').fileupload() // and U is lower case !!!!
```